# How is wavelet transform in practice handled for electrical signals?

Tags: signal-processing

To me it is a very complicated transform in terms of math and my question is not about the math side but the practical use.

How is wavelet transform in practice handled for electrical signals? Are circuit simulators like LTspice able to perform such transform for a given data samples? I read that if the signal is non-stationary, FFT is not good as wavelet transform.

I have DAQ board where I can couple an electrical signal and sample and log it. Later I want to do first FFT and then wavelet transform of that logged signal and see the differences. But I only have Python and LTspice as tools. My purpose is to make a setup and observe the differences for the sake of learning. Does anybody have experience  with that?

(I couldn't find any straightforward example. And most articles are about image processing.)

Comment: AFAIK, basically only signal processing (and image processing) experts use the wavelet transform. The rest of us just make do with fourier, unless we run into a particular problem with that approach. Then we go consult a signal processing expert.

Comment: With LTSpice and Python, you probably need to export your data from LTSpice and use Python to do any analysis requiring wavelet transform.

Comment: the wavelet offers some time-specific information about edges in the waveform. Is that useful to you?